# SetWindowPos returns Access Denied

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, user32

I'am building app that helps taking screenshots of selected windows. I'am displaying semi-transparent form over selected window. I'am using winapi in this case.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]

public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter,
                                       int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, int uFlags);
```

First parameter is handle to transparent form, to second I'am passing handle to selected window. Everything working just fine except one thing. When selected window is running with Administrator privileges I'am getting error  `"Access denied"`. Ofcourse, my app is running without administrator privileges and it need to stay that way.

Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: If you want to avoid the access denied error, you'll need to elevate your process. Why do you need to pass the target window as hWndInsertAfter?

Comment: Lets say that I have three open windows, not maximized, just dialogs. When a mouse pointer is over the second one I want to put beetwen he and next one in order (the last one visible), a semi-transparent form.

Comment: What flags are you passing?

Comment: SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040
and
NOACTIVATE = 0x0010

Comment: A non-elevated app can't access an elevated app, even to rearrange it's windows. That would be a potential security breach. (Imagine a non-elevated malware app that could watch for some elevated process and then send messages to make it do things the user might not want, or could access controls or grab information to which it shouldn't have access.)

Comment: Ken, you are right, but I'am only want to reorder windows. Anyway, do you have any other ideas how create this kind of application?